# How to make view container above Viewpager "scrollable" (Toolbar is inside Activity, not Fragment)?

Tags: android, scroll, android-viewpager, android-coordinatorlayout

I have `fragment`, which doesn´t cointains `toolbar`. `Toolbar` must stay in `activity`. This `fragment` must show main `view` and bellow `viewpager` with two `fragments`. Each `fragment` is specific. First use custom `layout`, second use `adapter`. Each has different height. I tried a lot of libs and ideas, but none of them works as it should (it made `scroll` longer/shorter than it should or it made crazy `UI` overlays).

I am trying to do `UI` where it looks that this all is one `layout`, meaning, it is scrollable from up to bottom. But I can´t figure it out. I was thinking to use `CoordinatorLayout`, but I have no idea how.

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:background="#FF0000"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="ABCDEFGH" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="GHIKJ" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

How to make this as scrollable `layout` in `fragment` without using `toolbar` references?

**Update: Yes, here are some pictures, I hope it is more clear now.**
[image]

Comment: Can you show your desired screen ? What you really want to achieve ?

Comment: Yes, please check images.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your `LinearLayout` inside an `AppBarLayout`. Actually `AppBarLayout` extends `LinearLayout` so you could just replace your `LinearLayout` with it.

Even if your app doesn't have a toolbar or an app bar, the `AppBarLayout` is the view that `CoordinatorLayout` coordinates with.

Adding the `AppBarLayout` should provide the behavior you're looking for.

Comment: So I can have more AppBarLayouts? Becuase I have already one in main activity?

Comment: Oh, re-reading the question, now I see your problem.  Please post the layout XML for your activity.

Answer (score 0):

**This root fragment layout seems to working. I am not sure that this is best solution, but it works.**

Note: I replaced listview by standard LinearLayout as root container and inflate child layouts (items) there.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**Child fragment (for viewpager):**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/childFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```